# URLretrieve - Return control to program when download fails/network error

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I'm writing a script to download videos from a website, using `urlretrieve`. My internet connection is somewhat erratic and goes down now and then.
When my network fails,  `urlretrieve` hangs, and  doesn't pass control back to my program so I can handle the error.
How do I go about solving this problem?
Or should I use a different library for this purpose? If so, which is the best one (considering all the other features of `urllib` are more than sufficient for my use and the files I download are around 500 - 600 MB)?

Comment: Use the requests lib, stream and write the data or just write the .content to a file catching any error with a try except. You can also set a timeout

Comment: @PadraicCunningham [This](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) one? I'll look into it. Thanks

Comment: Yep, you won't find better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. Requests will throw a `ConnectionError` [exception](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions) when problems with the Network arise. Refer to this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/how-to-download-large-file-in-python-with-requests-py) for how to go about downloading large files using requests.

If you're annoyed by the download starting all over again once the exception arises, look into the HTTP `Range` header, with which you'll be able to resume the download (provided you're saving the bytes already retreived somewhere in your exception handling code.)

Comment: I was worried cuz my current program support download resumption. I'll take look into `requests`. But I'm going to have to rewrite my entire code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it working. Completely switched my code from `urllib` to `requests`.